# Focus Event not working on Dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I was trying to initialize datePicker on dynamically added content. When i focus on datepicker, datepickerloaded but when i add a dynamic content, datePicker doesn't load for that content.
Here is the code for jquery datePicker on focus code.

```
 $('document').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```

HTML Part:

```
<div class="row" style="align-items: center;">
     <div class="col-md-10 dynamic-field" id="dynamic-field-1">
          <div class="row" >
               <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field" class="hidden-md">Type Of Cultivation*</label>
                                <input type="text" id="field" class="form-control" name="type_of_cultivation[]" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field" class="hidden-md">Cultivation Date</label>
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="2023-02-28" name="cultivation_date[]" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Harvest Date</label>
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="2023-03-28" name="harvest_date[]">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Quantity</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="quantity[]">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mt-30 append-buttons">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <button type="button" id="add-button" class="btn btn-secondary float-left text-uppercase shadow-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="remove-button" class="btn btn-secondary float-left text-uppercase ml-1" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-fw"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you've inserted the dynamic part outside of the `.datepicker` element?. Make also sure there's no transparent overlaying elements over the dynamically created elements.

Comment: I normally would fix this by putting the event listener on ajax success. Just put this
` $('document').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});` on ur success ajax callback it should work! Not the best way of solving though

Comment: *"HTML Part"* - is that the static (loaded with page) or is that the dynamic content (loaded via ajax) - if it's not the dynamic content, then does the dynamic content include the `datepicker` class on inputs?

Comment: Please confirm: is your `focus` event firing?   It should be.   (but just the datepicker part not working).

Comment: "HTML Part" - is that the static (loaded with page)  but when i click on add button dynamic content will load

Comment: Ideally, provide an *snippet* that demonstrates the issue (doesn't need to load HTML via ajax, can just add it via js) - at the very least, please specify exactly which of the 1000s of "datepicker"s you are using.

Comment: You comment *"that is the static part"* (at least that's how I read it) - so what's the dynamic part (the bit that *doesn't* work) look like?   No point showing us the code that *does* work.

Comment: I tried your code, *as provided*, and also doesn't work for the static HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/xcd2pej0/   this is because **focus event does not bubble** (to non-focusable elements) - so you cannot use it with event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an issue with initializing the datepicker on dynamically added content. The current implementation binds the datepicker to the focus event of elements with the class **.datepicker**. However, this approach is not effective when new content is added dynamically, as these elements are not present in the DOM at the time the binding occurs.

To address this issue, a solution would be to manually trigger the focus event on the newly added elements after they have been added to the DOM. This can be accomplished through the use of a click handler on the **#add-button** element, as follows:

```
$('#add-button').click(function() {
    // Add dynamic content here

    // Manually trigger the focus event on newly added elements with class 
   //.datepicker
    $('.datepicker').trigger('focus');
});
```

Comment: I have tried with your code but when i click add button the datepicker loaded but when i click second time on same button datePicker doesn't loaded .

Comment: The "normal" solution given what you've described would be to use *event delegation* - OP is already using event delegation.  This would be a common question if OP wasn't already using event delegation and has an oft-linked answer:  [Event Binding on Dynamically Created Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)